# Peeking deep into Queue

Tags: java, queue, peek

I'm using a `BlockingQueue`, and want to be able to peek into the next elements in the queue. `Queue.peek()` gives me the first next element, but I need to go deeper.

Is there a standard way, or should I implement it myself (which includes dealing with thread safety issues)?

Answer (score 0):

***queue.stream().peek(e -> System.out.println(e));***

While traversing you can do something on each element, then build your own elements.

```
    System.out.println(Stream.of("one", "two", "three", "four")
          .filter(e -> e.length() > 3)
          .peek(e -> System.out.println("After Filter: " + e))
          .map(String::toUpperCase)
          .peek(e -> System.out.println("After Mapped value: " + e))
          .collect(Collectors.toList()));


After Filter: three
After Mapping: THREE
After Filter: four
After Mapping: FOUR
[THREE, FOUR]
```

OR

```
    Queue<Boolean> qq = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);
    for(Boolean element : qq) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
```

Comment: It will be nice to use intellij :: Trace current stream chain feature, for lambda debugging, visual and easy.

Answer (score -1):

Understand the Data Structure you are using and the purpose of it.

You can do the same job by different data structures like [List,Set,Array,Vector,Stack,Queue and so on]. But everyone of them have their own features.

Queue is used for FIFO, where you access elements in the same way, **to access next element, first element should be moved out of it**.

Comment: This has t be a `BlockingQueue`, since that's it's main functionality. From time to time I need to review the queue content without harming other threads that `take()` from it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Elist, show me where you have seen that BlockingQueue or any other Queue implementation has this functionality

Comment: Remember, You can get all the elements of Queue by Iterating through it [unpredictable order], but you can never get FIFO order unless you remove the elements or implements your own Queue.

Answer (score -2):

Use while lopp for this

```
while ((value=q.poll())!=null)
            System.out.println(value);
    }
```

Comment: This will empty the Queue!